# Onclick buscando valor do input

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um código html que é inserido dentro de uma variável PHP

E dentro eu busco CEP, se eu uso

```
    <input alt='cep' class='text difCep' name='cep' id='cep' value='$cep'  type='text' onblur='xajax_procurarEndereco(this.value);$(\"#loading\").css(\"visibility\",\"visible\");' />
```

funciona de boa, mas o usuário quer um botão de pesquisa, então adaptei o código e ai está o problema, não consigo pegar o value de cep.
Testei com document.getElementById("campo") e $('#cep').val();

```
<label id='label_cep' for='cep'>CEP</label>
    <input alt='cep' class='text difCep' name='cep' id='cep' value='$cep'  type='text' />
    <button type='button' onclick='xajax_procurarEndereco(buscar input do cep);$("#loading").css("visibility","visible");' style="padding: 6px; height: 24px; margin-left: 10px;">Buscar</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ambos getElementById e a query do jQuery funcionam nesse caso, eu não posso pensar em outro problema que não seja você ter digitado errado, ou então usado aspas simples fechando assim as aspas que você abriu no HTML.
Veja o exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/ar64m2gL/

Comment: É melhor que você coloque o código de exemplo diretamente na sua resposta, porque se o link quebrar no futuro, sua resposta não terá mais tanta utilidade.

Comment: Eu jogo tudo isso dentro de uma variavel php, será que isso pode estar causando a não busca do valor?